# How to join "array" to a "parent array" with a common key. (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below are two arrays, `user_array` and `company_array`.

The `user_list` is grouped by `vendor_id`. I want to create bottom `group_list` array by adding a new `user_list` key to `company_list`.

I would like to know how to implement this one. Thank you in advance.

```json
const company_list =
[
    {
        "vendor_id": "62d884697df5ad65745001a9",
        "vendor_name": "vender_name_1",
    },
{
        "vendor_id": "add8846dad5ad657450s01a",
        "vendor_name": "vender_name_2",
    },
{
        "vendor_id": "34d8846dad5add57450sss3",
        "vendor_name": "vender_name_3",
    },
]
```

```
const user_list =
{
    "62d884697df5ad65745001a9": [
        {
            "user_id": "0e9a3faf-4dcc-4681-a153-2f6c7acd161d",
            "user_name": "user_1",
        },
        {
            "user_id": "f39769cb-e567-4da9-8e2c-9e39daaba9ed",
           "user_name": "user_2",
        }
    ],
    "add8846dad5ad657450s01a": [
        {
            "user_id": "de9adfaf-4dcc-d681-ad53-2f6cdacd161d",
            "user_name": "user_3",
        },
        {
            "user_id": "g397g9cb-e5g7-4dag-8e2cgge39daaba9",
           "user_name": "user_4",
        }
]
"34d8846dad5add57450sss3": [
        {
            "user_id": "deaadfaf-4dac-d6a1-ad5a-2f6adacd161a",
            "user_name": "user_5",
        },
        {
            "user_id": "g397b9cb-e5g7-4dab-8b2cgge39daaba9",
           "user_name": "user_6",
        }
]
}
```

```
const group_list =
[
    {
        "vendor_id": "62d884697df5ad65745001a9",
        "vendor_name": "vender_name_1",        
        “user_list” : [
            {
                "user_id": "0e9a3faf-4dcc-4681-a153-2f6c7acd161d",
                "user_name": "user_1",
            },
            {
                "user_id": "f39769cb-e567-4da9-8e2c-9e39daaba9ed",
               "user_name": "user_2",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "vendor_id": "add8846dad5ad657450s01a",
        "vendor_name": "vender_name_2",
        “user_list” : [
            {
                "user_id": "de9adfaf-4dcc-d681-ad53-2f6cdacd161d",
                "user_name": "user_3",
            },
            {
                "user_id": "g397g9cb-e5g7-4dag-8e2cgge39daaba9",
               "user_name": "user_4",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "vendor_id": "34d8846dad5add57450sss3",
        "vendor_name": "vender_name_3",
        “user_list” : [
            {
                "user_id": "deaadfaf-4dac-d6a1-ad5a-2f6adacd161a",
                "user_name": "user_5",
            },
            {
                "user_id": "g397b9cb-e5g7-4dab-8b2cgge39daaba9",
               "user_name": "user_6",
            },
        ],
     },
]
```

The grouping of user_list was achieved by implementing the following But, it is stuck at the point of merging user_list into company_list.

```js
const groupByCompany = async (array, key) => {
    const response = await array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
      (result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || []).push(
        currentValue
      );
      return result;
    }, {});
    return response;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have everything set up, just iterate through company list and get corresponding value from `user_list` object by a `vendor_id`.

```js
const company_list = [ { "vendor_id": "62d884697df5ad65745001a9", "vendor_name": "vender_name_1", }, { "vendor_id": "add8846da45d5ad657450s01a", "vendor_name": "vender_name_2", }, { "vendor_id": "34d8846dad5add57450sss3", "vendor_name": "vender_name_3", }, ]; 
const user_list = { "62d884697df5ad65745001a9": [ { "user_id": "0e9a3faf-4dcc-4681-a153-2f6c7acd161d", "user_name": "user_1", }, { "user_id": "f39769cb-e567-4da9-8e2c-9e39daaba9ed", "user_name": "user_2", } ], "add8846dad5ad657450s01a": [ { "user_id": "de9adfaf-4dcc-d681-ad53-2f6cdacd161d", "user_name": "user_3", }, { "user_id": "g397g9cb-e5g7-4dag-8e2cgge39daaba9", "user_name": "user_4", } ], "34d8846dad5add57450sss3": [ { "user_id": "deaadfaf-4dac-d6a1-ad5a-2f6adacd161a", "user_name": "user_5", }, { "user_id": "g397b9cb-e5g7-4dab-8b2cgge39daaba9", "user_name": "user_6", } ] };


console.log(company_list.map(it => ({...it, user_list: user_list[it.vendor_id] ? [...user_list[it.vendor_id]] : []})));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
We have confirmed that it works in the above case.

Also, if you don't mind, I would like to know how to handle the case where a vendor_id group that is not included in the company_list is included in the user_list.

In this case, it is ok to discard the user with a vendor_id not included in the company_list.

Comment: @MikeCoburn In this case you need to check if `user_list` contains a vendor id then do processing as `user_list[it.vendor_id] ? do something : assign empty array`

Answer (score 0):

Go through each company in your array, find a corresponding user list based on `vendor_id` and user list's key.

Quick example on how that can be achieved:

```
const merged = company_list.map((company) => {
    const matchingUserListEntry = Object.entries(user_list)
      .find(([key]) => key === company.vendor_id)[1];
   
  if (!matchingUerListEntry) {
    // handle missing user list
  }

  return {
    ...company,
    user_list: matchingUserListEntry,
  }
});

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const list = Object.keys(user_list)
const array = company_list.map(item=>{
if(list.includes(item.vendor_id)){
item['user_list'] = user_list[item.vendor_id]
}
return item
})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.